# I want to scroll down to the bottom of a web page with ease animation

Tags: jquery, html

I want to scroll down to the bottom of a web page with ease animation on clicking a link.In the bottom of my home page i have inserted a div class named wall.I have my menu as Home,Wall,contacts,overview.If i click 'wall' from my home page it should scroll down to bottom of page(remember the div class wall is on the same home page.)and when i am on another page say contacts and when i click wall in my menu the home page should be loaded and then should scroll down(Mind if the home is clicked the page opens and never scrolls).Is there any way to do so?
I designed website with html5 and used the following

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

     function pageScroll() {
            window.scrollBy(0,50); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
            scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()',20); 
// scrolls every 20 milliseconds
    }

      </script>
    <body onload="pageScroll()">
```

But the problem is that page scrolls down and never let the scroll to stop .Even if we scroll up it returns to the bottom...Is there any way to do the scroll only once?

I hardly know to spell jquery...Need help.

Answer (score 3):

It is as simple as

```
$('html, body').animate({ 
    scrollTop: $(document).height()-$(window).height()
});
```

And to scroll to a specific Id use the following

```
$("html, body").animate({ 
    scrollTop: $("#theID").scrollTop() 
}, 1000);
```

Comment: $(window).scrollTop() can be used to check if scroll is required

Answer (score 1):

Literally the first result after searching "scroll with easing jquery" on google was 
["Smooth vertical or horizontal page scrolling with JQuery"](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/02/smooth-vertical-or-horizontal-page-scrolling-with-jquery/) which does exactly what you're asking for. Study the contents of that page and remember to do your research before asking your question.

---

[Here's the vertical scroll](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/WebsiteScrolling/index_vertical.html) example from that page and here's the javascript code that does all the work.

```
$(function() {
    $('ul.nav a').bind('click',function(event){
        var $anchor = $(this);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');
        /*
        if you don't want to use the easing effects:
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1000);
        */
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

---

If you're new to JQuery and don't know where to begin, I suggest you start at their [tutorials page](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) to learn the basics. I'd also like to point out that it is recommended to have [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript), otherwise it can get messy mixing your javascript function calls in your HTML.

Also, I'm not sure if you know or not, but if you want to [link in javascript files](http://www.mkyong.com/javascript/how-to-link-an-external-javascript-file/) to your html you do this either in the head or body:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="external_javascript.js"></script>
```

Happy coding!